# How to sort PostgreSQL data by weeks over month period

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In simplest terms, I want to pull aggregate data from a table over a 4 week period but group by each week. It is safe to assume we can "force" a specific date or time (although it would be nice to allow any date entered and have the query run based on the date entered).

For example, the resulting data from a query would look like this:

```
start_date           |  end_date             |  count_of_sales
---------------------------------------------------------------
2014-03-03 04:00:00  |  2014-03-10 03:59:59  |  375
2014-03-10 04:00:00  |  2014-03-17 03:59:59  |  375
2014-03-17 04:00:00  |  2014-03-24 03:59:59  |  375
2014-03-24 04:00:00  |  2014-03-31 04:00:00  |  200
```

This would stem from unaggregated data that simply had a date (and of course other data but that is irrelevant):

```
saleDate             |  repID | productID
---------------------------------------------------------------
2014-03-04 12:36:33  |  1235  | 443
2014-03-09 07:08:12  |  1235  | 493
2014-03-09 10:12:44  |  3948  | 472
2014-03-21 23:33:01  |  2957  | 479
```

In my head the query would look SOMETHING (although accurate) like this:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date < '2014-03-31 04:00:00' GROUP BY date
```

I understand the query above however does not understand how far back to look (ideally the customer enters the final date and perhaps how many weeks prior of data they want to pull) which is why I left out a date BETWEEN clause (they may not know the exact 'start' date.

Sorry if this is confusing but hopefully the sample SQL (albeit wrong) and desired results will give a clearer picture

Comment: Can you post a sample of your unaggregated data with the table structure pls?

Comment: @I.K. think of it as just rows with a date

Comment: Your hypothetical query makes no sense. Unless you have an existing table structure (real or conjectured) with some data it is difficult to help you here.

Comment: @I.K. yes it does make sense I may just not be conveying it well enough. See my comment below the answer supplied. Inputs: date and number of weeks prior to pull, Output: the count of line items by week for as many weeks as selected

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, then following code should help you,
For clarification: Code which I have given is of SQL Server.

```
With CTE as 
(
    Select 1 as pID,'2014-03-03 04:00:00' as startDate,'2014-03-10 03:59:59' as endDate
    Union All
    Select 2,'2014-03-10 04:00:00','2014-03-17 03:59:59'
    Union All
    Select 3,'2014-03-17 04:00:00','2014-03-24 03:59:59'
    Union All
    Select 4,'2014-03-24 04:00:00','2014-03-31 04:00:00'

)
select a.pID,a.startDate,a.endDate,count(*) from CTE as a
inner join MyTable on myDateCol between a.startDate and a.endDate
group by a.pID,a.startDate,a.endDate
```

for demo **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c91f/1)**

Comment: thanks but the idea is the individual does not know the date ranges and should not be manually entering them himself/herself - I want them to enter a date and the number of weeks into a form (2 inputs) and output the count of line items in my table by week for as many weeks prior to the date entered.

Comment: Can you please explain with example, that what input you are going to take & from that what output is expected.